# Will we pronounce /t/ like a true T when /t/ is at beginning of a word but the syllable containing T is unstressed?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

[This website](http://pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=43) said

> The t is a regular, aspirated t sound when it is the first sound of a
>   word or a stressed syllable

A regular T is the one that is clearly aspirated.

So, my question is that:

Will we clearly aspirate the `/t/` (ie True `/t/`) when `/t/` is at beginning of a word but the syllable containing T is unstressed.

For example, **Tibet** `/tɪˈbet/` [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tibet), but I feel like `/t/` in **Tibet** is not aspirated clearly (Maybe 30% aspirated).

Whereas the `/t/` in **Thai** `/tai/` is aspirated clearly.

Comment: [This website](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/vot-is-more.html) seems to say that words like *Tibet* beginning with a stop and a weak vowel in an unstressed syllable are unaspirated. But many other /t/s are "slightly aspirated" (meaning somewhere between and less-than-full aspiration).

Comment: What does "unaspirated" mean? There is no air come out of our mouth?

Comment: It means it's not aspirated ... of course there is still some air coming out of our mouth, but nowhere near as much as in aspiration.

Comment: "unaspirated", "slightly aspirated" & "fully aspirated": what are the differences?

Comment: *Aspirated* means there is a lot of air coming out of the mouth. *Unaspirated* means there is very little (it's may be impossible to pronounce /t/ without using any air). And "slightly aspirated" means somewhere in between ... or maybe it essentially means the amount of aspiration is optional; I'm not sure.

Comment: So, "unaspirated" & "Glottal stop" are different right? cos this website say that: "**The letter t is pronounced as a glottal stop /ʔ/ (the sound in the middle of the word uh-oh) when it follows a vowel, n sound, or r sound (including all r-controlled vowels) and is followed by an n sound, schwa+n sound, m sound, or non-syllablic l sound.**" http://pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=43

Comment: Yes, they're quite different. And what that website says doesn't hold for all English dialect; just some American ones.

Comment: I can't really help with this; Scots don't pronounce Ts. :P

Comment: I do not agree "**They are unaspirated  when followed by any FRICATIVE, as in lapse læps, depth depθ &  if immediately followed by another plosive as with the k in doctor ˈdɒktə || ˈdɑːktər. The release stage of the first plosive is then usually inaudible (‘masked’).**". Other American meterial said, all stop consonants will not be released if it was followed by any consonant.

Comment: What is the real difference between *"the release stage is inaudible"* and *"the stop consonants will not be released"*. ***Can you hear the difference?*** And if you can't, why bother with this distinction?

Comment: This website is perfect, can asnwer my question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant

Comment: @PeterShor,  Here they said "**voiceless stops are sometimes aspirated, while voiced stops are usually unaspirated.**" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant), so do we vibrate our vocal cords when we make "**unaspirated T /P / K**"?

Comment: @PeterShor, what is the difference between /b/ and unaspirated /p/, /d/ & unaspirated /t/, /g/ & unaspirated /k/?

Comment: In Mandarin Chinese (and probably other varieties as well), I believe they're allophones. In English, your vocal cords vibrate when you pronounce /b/, /d/, and /g/, and not with unaspirated /p/, /t/, and /k/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, t is aspirated at the beginning of a syllable when the vowel after the t is unstressed.  Other examples are "today", "tomorrow".

In light of this, since of course t is also aspirated when at the beginning of a syllable and before a stressed vowel, the stress of the vowel is evidently immaterial to whether the t will be aspirated.

The aspiration of t is more noticeable before a stressed vowel than it is before an unstressed vowel because the entire onset of a syllable whose vowel is stressed is more prominent.